# SwiftUI Update Model with Button and Increase amount

Tags: swiftui

i want to increase a product of its tapped count. so if the user press a button the Model needs to be updated and the amount += 1
I try the following code and the model does not update the amount.

```
struct GridCell: View {
@EnvironmentObject var order: Order

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    @Published var product : Product {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(product: Product) {
        self.product = product
    }

    public func increaseAmount() {
        self.product.amount += 1
        self.objectWillChange.send()
        print("\(self.product.amount) / \(self.product.id)")
    }
}

func updatePos(){
    self.viewModel.increaseAmount()
    let itempreis = viewModel.product.preis
    order.totalAmount += itempreis
    print(order.totalAmount)
}

@ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  var body: some View {
      Button(action: {
         print("TAPPED")
         self.updatePos()
      }) {
      ...
  }
}
```

and `GridCell` would be

```
GridCell(viewModel: GridCell.ViewModel(product: $0))
```

and `Product` is

```
struct Product : Identifiable, Equatable, Decodable {
   var id: String
   var name: String
   let preis: Double
   var amount: Int
}
```

In my print statement the amount is not updating and every time I press the button the value is like 1.
What did I forget?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public func increaseCharacterStrength() {
      self.product.amount += 1
}
```

Because `Product` is a struct when you were creating the variable `var viewproduct = self.product` you were creating a local copy of product, so `viewproduct.amount += 1` just increases the amount for that local variable, not for the actual model.

Comment: struct Product : Identifiable, Decodable, Equatable{
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var amount: Int   
}

Comment: i added the @Published var product : Product in the ViewModel Class but nothing changed. the amount is every time just 1.

Comment: thanks but it changed nothing  :( i tryd this before.

Comment: if i change it to 99 the amount would be 99. but not increase

Comment: @xyzcodeeee I tried your code and using the method I posted it seems to work fine, what xcode version are you using ?

Comment: This is what I get, isn't what you want? `TAPPED
---- 1 / 23864DBD-9D91-4005-96C2-C51B9C30E9C9
TAPPED
---- 2 / 23864DBD-9D91-4005-96C2-C51B9C30E9C9
TAPPED
---- 3 / 23864DBD-9D91-4005-96C2-C51B9C30E9C9`

Comment: yes i want to increase the amount on every tap. and Xcode 11.2

Comment: we try d different options to get this runnin . but every time the amount is 1.
anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not defining view model correctly.  Since I do not have the structure of the product and order, I simplified the model to meet the needs of our discussion.  For the example provided below, you can create the instance of GridCell (like GridCell()) and tapping the button increases the quantity by 1.  Also note one can simplify further by using @Published property wrapper in the view model instead of Passthrough

```swift
class Order: ObservableObject {

    @Published var totalAmount : Int = 0

}

struct Product {

    var id = UUID()
    var amount: Int = 0
    var preis: Int = 0


}

struct GridCell: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var order: Order

    func updatePos() {
        self.viewModel.increaseCharacterStrength()
        let itempreis = self.viewModel.product.preis
        order.totalAmount += itempreis
        //print(order.totalAmount)
        print("---- \(self.viewModel.product.amount) / \(self.viewModel.product.id)")
    }

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel(product: Product())

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("TAPPED")
            self.updatePos()
        }) {
            Text("Increase order")

        }
    }

}


class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject < Void,
                Never > ()
        var product: Product {
                willSet {
                        self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
        }

        init(product: Product) {
                self.product = product
        }

        public func increaseCharacterStrength() {
                self.product.amount += 1
                self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
}
```

Comment: if i try this i got an error
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Product' with no arguments.

Comment: I added the above code in a new project and it was working.  Please note that you need to create the environment object and add it to the view before calling this.  Also product should not fail with the error as everything been given value.  Of course, this is only for our testing purpose.

Comment: my product looks like 
struct Product : Identifiable, Decodable, Equatable{ var id: String var name: String var amount: Int }

Comment: is there a workable demo that has the issue you are talking about.

Comment: hope you saw my earlier update.  if I do not have a demo, I am not sure how you are composing the view and how the navigation of the views.  Otherwise I need to assume the navigation path which might not give the result that we want.  Further, we do not have any cancellable token that we store (this kind of subject is handled by combine) and it is my understanding that once we dereference the publisher, the associated elements get deallocated.  so without looking at how the various views work, it might be difficult to provide any solution.

Comment: no demo sorry . i try to find a solution to increase the model if the user is tapped on a button and later i want to send just the model array.  i import combine  to handle this. and i update the code to let u know about. hope you can help me with this.

Comment: we try d different options to get this runnin . but every time the amount is 1.
anyone find a solution?